# WebRTC - sync incoming peer audio streams

Tags: javascript, audio, synchronization, webrtc, latency

I tryed googling on how to synchronize multiple audio streams coming from webRTC peers into one main stream, but i can't find anything out there.

Usually streams can have from 20ms up to 1s delay/latency, depending on the network status usually, bandwidths etc

Is out there any way to synchronize them if they have too much latency?

Comment: To clarify, you don't want to synchronize the latency of both streams, you just want to drop excess buffer if the latency exceeds a threshold?

Comment: or do you want to buffer all streams to make sure that you only play packets at the correct time?